# Setting up tkinter label to display countdown timer

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a pomodoro timer which will display different countdowns on click of one of three button options.

The problem here is that every time I click a button after previously clicking one, the label struggles with which of the timers to display. It tries to display both timer countdowns at the same time.

I need the label to stop displaying the first button's timer countdown when I click on another button. Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super(Application,self).__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):

        self.labelvariable = StringVar()
        self.labelvariable.set("25:00")

        self.thelabel = Label(self,textvariable = self.labelvariable,font=('Helvetica',50))
        self.thelabel.pack(side=TOP)

        self.firstButton = Button(self,text="pomodoro",command=self.pomodoro)
        self.firstButton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.secondButton = Button(self,text="short break",command=self.shortBreak)
        self.secondButton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.thirdButton = Button(self,text="long break",command=self.longBreak)
        self.thirdButton.pack(side=LEFT)

    def pomodoro(self):
        countdown(1500)

    def shortBreak(self):
        countdown(300)

    def longBreak(self):
        countdown(600)





def countdown(timeInSeconds):
    mins,secs = divmod(timeInSeconds,60)
    timeformat = "{0:02d}:{1:02d}".format(mins,secs)
    app.labelvariable.set(timeformat)
    root.after(1000,countdown,timeInSeconds-1)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Timer")
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use after_cancel() to cancel the previous after() call http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm  I would suggest that you wait something like 1/10 of a second and issue another after_cancel() in case you hit the small spot where the program is in the function, but above the after() statement.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution. This one moves the `countdown` function into the `Application` class and makes it free-running. Then I added a class attribute to track the current time left and just decrement that to 0. This does have the downside that it could take almost a second to show the new count.

```
from tkinter import *
from threading import Event

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super(Application,self).__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()
        self._count = 0
        self.countdown()

    def createWidgets(self):

        self.labelvariable = StringVar()

        self.thelabel = Label(self,textvariable = self.labelvariable,font=('Helvetica',50))
        self.thelabel.pack(side=TOP)

        self.firstButton = Button(self,text="pomodoro",command=self.pomodoro)
        self.firstButton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.secondButton = Button(self,text="short break",command=self.shortBreak)
        self.secondButton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.thirdButton = Button(self,text="long break",command=self.longBreak)
        self.thirdButton.pack(side=LEFT)

    def pomodoro(self):
        self._count = 1500

    def shortBreak(self):
        self._count = 300

    def longBreak(self):
        self._count = 600

    def countdown(self):
        mins,secs = divmod(self._count,60)
        timeformat = "{0:02d}:{1:02d}".format(mins,secs)
        app.labelvariable.set(timeformat)
        if self._count > 0:
            self._count -= 1
        root.after(1000,self.countdown)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Timer")
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

---

Here is another option based on Curly Joe's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45471009/setting-up-tkinter-label-to-display-countdown-timer/45471567?noredirect=1#comment77903917_45471009). This one uses `after_cancel` to stop the currently running countdown by cancelling the next alarm. It has the benefit that the new countdown starts immediately.

```
from tkinter import *


class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super(Application,self).__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()
        self._alarm_id = None

    def createWidgets(self):

        self.labelvariable = StringVar()
        self.labelvariable.set("25:00")

        self.thelabel = Label(self,textvariable = self.labelvariable,font=('Helvetica',50))
        self.thelabel.pack(side=TOP)

        self.firstButton = Button(self,text="pomodoro",command=self.pomodoro)
        self.firstButton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.secondButton = Button(self,text="short break",command=self.shortBreak)
        self.secondButton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.thirdButton = Button(self,text="long break",command=self.longBreak)
        self.thirdButton.pack(side=LEFT)

    def pomodoro(self):
        if self._alarm_id is not None:
            self.master.after_cancel(self._alarm_id)
        self.countdown(1500)

    def shortBreak(self):
        if self._alarm_id is not None:
            self.master.after_cancel(self._alarm_id)
        self.countdown(300)

    def longBreak(self):
        if self._alarm_id is not None:
            self.master.after_cancel(self._alarm_id)
        self.countdown(600)

    def countdown(self, timeInSeconds):
        mins,secs = divmod(timeInSeconds, 60)
        timeformat = "{0:02d}:{1:02d}".format(mins, secs)
        app.labelvariable.set(timeformat)
        self._alarm_id = self.master.after(1000, self.countdown, timeInSeconds-1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Timer")
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There's no reason to do `self.after(0, self.countdown)`. Just call it directly: `self.countdown()`.

Comment: This is great. Thank you all very much

Comment: @BryanOakley That's a good point. I used `after` to delay actually running `countdown` until the mainloop starts. The benefit in this case is pretty negligible, though.

Comment: Can I ask a follow up question here or do I have to ask it separately?

Comment: @RomeoFolie What is the question?

Comment: @FamousJameous I want to know how I can implement start, pause, and reset features on a running countdown? Any ideas on that?

Comment: @RomeoFolie I could try to add that to this answer, but I think you will get a better, more complete answer by asking in a new post. I would suggest you give it a try yourself first and then post your code/requirements/problems. I'll keep an eye out for it.